# How to convert a "flat" SQL output into columns format?

Tags: sql

I appreciate any ideas you might have!

I work with a product that allows custom properties to be made, and it writes them to the database table like this, creating a new *row* per custom property per computer, not a new *column*.

```
ID | Name | Value
------------------
123,Manufacturer,Dell
123,Model,Latitude E5450
456,Manufacturer,HP
456,Model,ProBook 450 G3
```

For my query result, I want to "collapse" the data result so that it looks like this, giving it "columns" again -- one record per computer.

```
ID|Manufacturer|Model
123,Dell,Latitude E5450
456,HP,ProBook 450 G3
```

I tried this approach:

```
SELECT MainTable.ID,
mtManufacturer.Value as 'Manufacturer',
mtModel.Value as 'Model'
FROM MainTable
JOIN MainTable mtManufacturer ON MainTable.ID=mtManufacturer.ID AND mtManufacturer.Name='Manufacturer'
JOIN MainTable mtModel ON MainTable.ID=mtModel.ID AND mtModel.Name='Model'
```

However, this gives me inaccurate results, like this:

```
ID|Manufacturer|Model
123,Dell,Latitude E5450 --good
123,Dell,ProBook 450 G3 --bad
456,HP,Latitude E5450 --bad
456,HP,ProBook 450G3 --good
```

What did I goof up? Also, I simplified the database -- I only need two of the custom properties, but there are ~180-200 of them.

Comment: You might be interested in [pivoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) your table

Comment: How do I pivot when I have no mathematical/aggregate function that I want to perform? Examples online use SUM, AVERAGE, etc. I just want to put data pertaining to the same computer (ID=123) on one line (Computer with ID 123 is a Dell Latitude E5450) and for the next computer (ID=456) on another (ID 456 is an HP ProBook 450 G3) and so on.

Comment: `MAX(A,B)` will return `A` if `B` is `NULL`.  So you can use `MAX` if you use `CASE` to `NULL` alternative columns.

Comment: @PM77-1, promising approach. Working on that now. I guess I will need to use the MAX results as subqueries, one per property. Figuring that out now.

Comment: @PM77-1, I still have a similar problem, query looks like this:


`SELECT mt.ID, tMan.Manufacturer, tMod.Model
FROM MainTable mt
JOIN (
   SELECT ID, MAX(Value) as 'Manufacturer'
   FROM MainTable
   WHERE Name='Manufacturer'
   GROUP BY ID
) tMan ON mt.ID=tMan.ID
JOIN (
   SELECT ID, MAX(Value) as 'Model'
   FROM MainTable
   WHERE Name='Model'
   GROUP BY ID
) tModel ON mt.ID=tModel.ID`


But gives me the same inaccurate result described in the original post.

Comment: No sub-queries, straight `GROUP BY` after creating your columns with `CASE`

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each ID has exactly one manufacturer and exactly one model, you can do something like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ID, NAME, Value FROM Product) up
PIVOT(MAX(Value) FOR NAME IN ([Manufacturer],[Model])) AS pvt
ORDER BY ID
GO
```

Notice that I use the `MAX` aggregate function which should still result in a valid result based on the assumption that each ID has exactly one manufacturer and exactly one model. If this assumption isn't true, then the `MAX` aggregate function will probably not behave as you expect it to.

You can verify all of this by running the following code:

```
-- Creating Test Table
CREATE TABLE Product(ID VARCHAR(25), Name VARCHAR(20), Value VARCHAR(20))
GO

-- Inserting Data into Table
INSERT INTO Product(ID, Name, Value)
VALUES(123,'Manufacturer','Dell')
INSERT INTO Product(ID, Name, Value)
VALUES(123,'Model','Latitude E5450')
INSERT INTO Product(ID, Name, Value)
VALUES(456,'Manufacturer','HP')
INSERT INTO Product(ID, Name, Value)
VALUES(456,'Model','ProBook 450 G3')
GO

-- Selecting and checking entires in table
SELECT *
FROM Product
GO

-- Pivot Table ordered by ID
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ID, NAME, Value FROM Product) up
PIVOT(MAX(Value) FOR NAME IN ([Manufacturer],[Model])) AS pvt
ORDER BY ID
GO

-- Clean up database
DROP TABLE Product
GO
```

Comment: Assuming that OPs SQL implementation supports `PIVOT`.

Comment: Thank you, @user1348796! Using PIVOT(MAX() FOR solved it!